# I am getting an error with pip installing Packages

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

Here is the error I am getting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\tejch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\tejch\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I just installed python on windows and I have no idea what is causing this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: my apologies, i forgot to mention this is after attempting to install PyAudio after running the following command:

```
C:\Users\tejch> pip install PyAudio
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Provide more information if you need help. Your installing python and running visual studio seems unrelated.

Comment: sorry about that, I added some more info.

Comment: As for the error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27stdio.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `pip3 install PyAudio`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I got the same error.